# Como utilizar a funcionalidade ruleset do FluentValidation em Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

Gostaria de utilizar uma funcionalidade do [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/) chamada *ruleset* num projeto em Web API, porque não quero ter que ficar fazendo a validação dos models manualmente toda vez que um *action method* é chamado.

Então utilizei o [`FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.WebApi/FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.cs#L44) para adicionar o FluentValidation ao [`ModelValidatorProviders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.validation.modelvalidatorprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) para que meus models fossem automaticamente validados antes de serem enviados para um *action method*.

Até esse ponto tudo tudo bem, mas para eu continuar a configuração do FluentValidation no meu projeto, para que ele faça as validações automaticamente, só falta eu utilizar o atributo [`CustomizeValidatorAttribute`](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.Mvc4/CustomizeValidatorAttribute.cs) nos models que desejados da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResul Something([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "RuleName")]MyModel myModel)
```

O problema é que esse atributo só está disponível para o pacote mais específico do FluentValidation que é destinado ao ASP.NET MVC. O que eu poderia fazer para ter essa funcionalidade no Web API?

Comment: Segundo [esse issue](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/80) não há previsão para essa integração.

Comment: +1 Por me apresentar `FluentValidation` :)

Comment: Não tem resposta, não da pra fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [esse issue](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/80), no próprio GitHub do projeto, não tem como fazer isso e o autor não tem intenção de fazer, não em um futuro próximo.

Segue o texto, em inglês, do autor:

> No plans to make a WebApi version of CustomizeValidator (unless someone wants to submit a pull request), sorry.
>
> There are unlikely to be any more changes to the mvc/webapi integration now - all future development efforts in this area will be focused on integration with ASP.NET 6 with the new combined mvc/webapi.
>
> --[JeremySkinner](https://github.com/JeremySkinner)

Lembrando também que isso foi em 12 Junho 2015, e não achei informações se mais alguém implementou algo e não enviou o pull.